# How to pass JSF value to from a backing bean to another backing bean?

Tags: jsf

my problem is that i want to pass a value (id of the logged in user) to a page.
the following code shows the link to the page

```
<h:form>
   <h:link outcome="Account">
       #{logging.username}
   </h:link>
</h:form>
```

so i want to pass the "logging.id to the "Account" when that page loads i want to pass the id to another backing bean used by that Account page.
so what is the way to do this ?
please kindly help me

Comment: This question has been asked a billion times. [Start here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters) and see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i am concerned, the logged in user is a session property rather than a request/page property.

For that matter, you could save the user.id in the session attribute, and rather than passing it to another page through a url request, you get it from the session from any backing bean you so require it from.

example:

```
public void login(String username, String password ){
  UserAccount account = myManagerBean.findUser(username, password);
  HttpSession session = getCurrentRequestFromFacesContext().getSession(false);
  session.addAttribute("user.account", account);
}
```

And then from any other backing bean.

```
public UserAccount getUserAccount() {
  HttpSession session = getCurrentRequestFromFacesContext().getSession(false);
  return session.getAttribute("user.account");
}
```

But if thats now what you require, you could pass the id as a request parameter:

```
<h:form>
   <h:link outcome="Account">
       <f:param name="user.username" value="#{logging.username}"/>
   </h:link>
</h:form>
```

You could then attach this directly to a backing bean property of a request scope bean or manually retrieve it from the request:

```
@RequestScope

public class MyAccountBean {

 @ManagedProperty("user.username")
 private String username;

 ... or ...
 public String getUserName() {
   return getCurrentRequestFromFacesContext().getParameter("user.username");
 }
}
```